# Print all Variants of a Quiz

Tags: exsheets

I'm trying to write different versions of quizzes, and am trying to find a streamlined way of doing it.  I have found exsheets, and this works (but I'm open to other suggestions if you have any).   The code below works perfectly but to print the different versions, I need to uncomment the appropriate variant.  Instead, I'd like to produce three pages.  Something like

`for i in [1,2,3] do \newpage do the ith variant`

but I don't know how to get latex to do this.

Here's my minimal working example:  Thank you for any help!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetVariations{3}
\begin{document}

%\variant{1}
\variant{2}
%\variant{3}

This is quiz for the  \vary{2:30}{3:35}{4:40} class.

\begin{question}
$\vary{1}{2}{3} + \vary{5}{6}{7}$
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

EDIT:  For my purposes I found a solution, since my main tex file contains a lot of `\input` statements.  So I can just do `\newpage` `\setvariant{1}`  `\input{quiz}` ... etc.   But I wonder if there's a way to just do this in a standalone way.

Comment: I think your MWE is missing a `\documentclass`

Comment: thanks - it was there, i just didn't end the line after ```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a job for [TikZ](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)'s `\foreach` --- to do the looping, and then I agree with your EDIT, that it's easiest to put the quiz content in another file and `\input` it.

##### MWE:

*main.tex*

```latex
\documentclass{article} % assumed
\usepackage{tikz} % new
\pagestyle{empty} % consider adding this too ...
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetVariations{3}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {1,...,3}{ % core solution
  \variant{\i}
  \input{quiz}
  \newpage
}
\end{document}
```

*quiz.tex*

```latex
This is quiz for the  \vary{2:30}{3:35}{4:40} class.

\begin{question}
$\vary{1}{2}{3} + \vary{5}{6}{7}$
\end{question}
```